# Article comparison in "un francese e due svizzeri" and "uno svizzero e due francesi"

Tags: grammar, articles

1) "***un*** francese e due svizzeri"

2) "***uno*** svizzero e due francesi"

Do the bolded ***un*** and ***uno*** mean the same thing? If so, can 1) be rewritten this way:

3) "uno francese e due svizzeri"

If not, can anyone explain the difference between 1) and 3)?

Comment: I have no time for a real answer, but the issue here – apart from the specific form before a vowel or certain consonants – is that “un, uno” may be: 1) an indeterminative article; b) a pronoun; c) an adjective; d) a noun; and its meanings and use are somewhat different in the various cases. Some clarifications here: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/uno/

Comment: @DaG, sometimes, as it is the case here, a comment is better than nothing, thank you.

Comment: Also to note that the form 3) is correct if `uno` is used like a pronoun... Ex: "Ieri ho comprato tre orologi: uno francese e due svizzeri"

Answer (score 17):

Feminine nouns pose almost no problem, because the indeterminate article is only *una*, that's subject to elision in front of vowels. On the other hand, with masculine nouns, the usage of *un* and *uno* reflects the usage of *il* and *lo*.
If a word starts by “s” followed by a consonant (and the digraph “sc” also follows the rule), the articles for it must be “lo” and ”uno” (determinate and indeterminate). So the rest of the answer is about masculine nouns.

The same happens for words starting with “gn”, ”z”, ”ps”: *uno gnocco*, *lo zio*, *lo psicologo*. For *pneumatico* the standard should be “lo” and “uno”, but “il” and “un” are frequent. Also words starting with consonantic “i” want “lo” and ”uno” (*iato* = *hyatus*), although this is disputed and someone says *l'iato*.

The other words want “il” and ”un”. Thus, *uno francese* is not Italian. The usage of “lo” was more liberal in the past and you find *lo duca mio* in Dante's “Commedia”. You also find *il zappatore* in Leopardi's “Il sabato del villaggio”. For this, when I was at the elementary school, the teacher said *licenza poetica*, but the usage was not really consistent at the time the poem was written.

When foreign words are concerned, the situation is fluid. Somebody swears for *l'whisky*, other (I among them) say *il whisky* (Luciano Satta wrote about this defending “il” and “un” before *whisky*).

Dialects are of course different. In Veneto we commonly say *il gnocco* without any problem.

---

A different situation is when “uno” is a pronoun rather than an article. In this case the only form is *uno*. Thus, *ho tre amici stranieri, uno francese e due svizzeri“; the verbs *è* and *sono* are implicit and the complete sentence would be *ho tre amici stranieri, uno è francese e due sono svizzeri*.

Comment: egr., thank you, interesting. May I ask you if there exist the female version of *il gnocco*, e.g., *la gnocca*?

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis It's a vulgar word.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Yes, there is, but it's a vulgar word equivalent to English _cunt_, even when used to mean a woman.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Just a note: in some parts of Italy _una gnocca_ can mean "a really beautiful woman" and in that case it's not vulgar (but still colloquial)

Comment: @miniBi., thank you, in fact I have heard "una gnocca", especially when I was living in Bologna, a city located in Emilia-Romagna. But I never found it in written Italian, at least not in newspapers.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Indeed its origin is from Bologna, as far as I know. Look closely and you'll sometimes find it also in newspapers, mostly when reporting speech.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis that's because it colloquial. Another idiomatic saying on that line is "una gnocca da paura", which means "an incredibly beautiful woman" (by the way "gnocca" leans on sexiness rather than "pure beauty"). Also beware that "la gnocca" is a synonim for cunt, although not as vulgar (it can also figuratively means "sexy/beautiful _women_" like in "c'era un sacco di gnocca ieri al bar")

Comment: "l'iato"? *brrr* :|

Comment: @Alenanno I'm really sure to have read it, and not once.

Comment: To further expand this answer, we are talking about masculine nouns here.

Comment: @martina Good remark, I added it as a prologue.

Comment: Does that mean the usage of *un* vs *uno* is aligned with *il* vs *lo* (or *l'*)?

Comment: @iBug Yes, in modern Italian that's the rule.

Answer (score 3):

*Un* is an elision of *uno*, which is used before words starting with vowel or consonant; *uno* is used with words starting with *impure S*,  *Z*, *X*, *gn*, *pn*, *ps*. (*Impure S* is an S followed by a consonant.)

- *Un albero*
- *Un cane*
- *Uno stagno*
- *Un francese*
- *Uno xilofono*
- *Uno pneumatico*
- *Uno zio*

About *uno svizzero and uno francese* in *ho due orologi, uno svizzero ed uno francese*, that is not using the indefinite article, but it is using a numeral; it is similar to the following sentence.

> Ho sei orologi: due francesi, uno russo e tre tedeschi.

*Uno svizzero e un francese* would be understood as referring to two people: a person from Switzerland and one from France.

Comment: kiamla, but can I say "*ho due orologi, uno francese e uno svizzero*" or "*ho due orologi, uno svizzero e uno francese*"? Or, maybe, do these sentences break some rule?

Comment: It would seem acceptable to me, since _un francese e un svizzero_ would make me think you are talking of an inhabitant of France and an inhabitant of Switzerland.

Comment: kiamla, I can't tell for sure, but "un svizzero" breaks the rule suggested in splattne's answer, though.

Comment: Right, because that is a word starting for _impure S_. Still, _un francese_ would make me think of _an inhabitant of France_.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis in that sentence _uno_ is not an article but a pronoun. Compare **un** _francese_ -> **a** _french_ (person), **uno** _francese_ -> a _french_ **one** (object)

Answer (score 2):

Both *un* e *uno* are indeterminate articles (as *a* in English). For masculine words *un* is normally used, but you have to use *uno* if the following word (a noun or an adjective) starts with *gn*, *ps*, *z*, *x*, *y*, *s* + consonant.

Answer (score 0):

They are both masculine but there are some rules to use both of them.

### **Un**

"Un" is used for any Italian nouns exept starting with z or s + consonant, for example

> **Un** albergo
>
> **Un** gatto

### **Uno**

"Uno" is used for any nouns starting with z or s + consonant, for example

> **Uno** stadio
>
> **Uno** zio

The answer to your question:

Difference between 1 and 3 is that 1 is correct because like I said, `un` is used for any nouns except ending in z or s + consonant and the noun does not start with any of them. But for 3, it is incorrect because like I also said, `uno` is used for nouns ending in z or s + consonant, so therefore 3 does not even exist!

For extra information, feminine nouns that begin with a vowel, you use `un'`, but for feminine nouns that begin with any consonant, you use `una`.

Comment: *Uno stazione*?

Comment: @egreg: Stazione is female term, so use una