# Forma corretta in "trentuno annate"

Tags: orthography, apocope

leggendo [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1141/95), mi è venuto in mente che non saprei come scrivere

> ho collezionato trentuno annate di *Uncinetto estremo*.

"Annata" è femminile, ma "trentuno" è invariabile; non ce la farei proprio a scrivere "trentun'annate", mi spiace. Voi che fareste, a parte non fare né elisione o troncamento oppure girare la frase come nella barzelletta di chi scrive una lettera a un canile "buongiorno, vorrei prendere due pastori belg...belgh... vabbè: vorrei prendere un pastore belga, anzi due"?

Comment: Si dice "[trentun pagine](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trentuno/)", "[trentun annate](http://fratellirosselli.fol.it/quaderni/Indice%20completo%20dei%20QCR%20.pdf)" (proprio perché "trentuno" è invariabile).

Answer (score 3):

In passato si scriveva “ventuna pagina”, per esempio [qui (1756)](http://books.google.it/books?id=MEdXAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA58&dq=%22ventuna%20pagina%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=nbLSU6Fag87KA4KFgcgN&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22ventuna%20pagina%22&f=false) e [qui (1780)](http://books.google.it/books?id=tz4wfXnjaqwC&pg=PA27&dq=%22ventuna%20pagina%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=nbLSU6Fag87KA4KFgcgN&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22ventuna%20pagina%22&f=false), ma, sinceramente, “ventuno cavallo” mi parrebbe alquanto affettato e arcaico. Ne scriveva [Luciano Satta](http://books.google.it/books?id=N5QdAQAAIAAJ&q=%22ventuno%20cavallo%22&dq=%22ventuno%20cavallo%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=G7PSU7uuGuXnygP_94GIBA&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ) suggerendo il problema di *ventuno cavallo bianchi* o *ventuno cavallo bianco*?

Ormai si dice *trentun anni*, *trentuno valigie* e l'invariabilità dice che l'ortografia è *trentun annate*. Il caso di *buono* è diverso: da *buono amico* viene *buon amico* perché si può dire *buon compleanno*; da *buona amica* viene *buon'amica* perché non si può elidere/troncare davanti a consonante.

Obiezione: non si può dire *trentun sedie*! Vero, ma la parola è la stessa sia per il maschile sia per il femminile. E, ripensandoci, *trentun sedie* non mi fa tutta questa impressione. Poi, fa' come ti pare. Se hai l'incertezza, scrivi *trentun'annata* e aggiungi che per te i secoli non sono passati. Ma attento: *trentun'annata rilegata* o *trentun'annata rilegate*? `;-)`